# Ember Unit testing: counting new items rendering

Tags: ember.js

I wrote a controller that holds a list, and by clicking a "get more" button, renders 5 more items of that list. I want to create some tests for that, and I want to validate that it only renders 5 more items (instead of re-rendering the entire list).
Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm using a relatively older Ember version: 1.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very depends on what 're-rendering' is for you.

You can check if IDs of the old items were not changed and if their state is still valid. This was an issue that I have to solve by using Ember.ArrayProxy.

If you want to test if browser have to re-render it, you can try to count number of execution of 'init' method - https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/

Comment: Thanks, I will try the 'init' thing.